# React native expo Audio not working properly

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I have a react native app running with expo, sounds where working great.

For some reason, the simple code for loading a sound, without playing it or any other action, is returning an error.

Both:

```
const mySound = new Audio.Sound(require('./assets/sounds/mySound.mp3'))
```

and

```
const mySound = new Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('./assets/sounds/mySound.mp3'))
```

end up in the next error:

Error: An unknown error occurred (-12746) - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11800 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".

I have tried hosting the mp3 files in my server and download using the url, same result.
No clue what to do as the Audio documentation from expo has no explanation for the error codes